# Error: Invalid Chai property: __wd_promise_enriched

Tags: node.js, chai

For some reason I keep getting this error.  Here is the offending line of code

`.elementByXPath('//textarea').getAttribute('innerHTML').should.eventually.equal('abcdefg')`

I've used elementByXPath, getAttribute, and a should eventually statement elsewhere in the code and it works ok.  What does it even mean to have a _wd_promise_enriched error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the same problem and wasn't able to understand why it happened specifically. However, I worked around it with `become`, so your code would turn into:

```
.elementByXPath('//textarea').getAttribute('innerHTML').should.become('abcdefg')
```

This is equivalent to:

```
.elementByXPath('//textarea').getAttribute('innerHTML').should.eventually.deep.equal('abcdefg')
```